# SQL Query : how to Select Maximum value of each group of joined tables

Tags: sql, join, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have this problem of returning maximum AGE of players in these 2 tables I have, Table tblplayers (with 34 records) when this table is joined to another table called tblClubs (with 9 records).

tblPlayers fields are:

```
ID(Autonumber) | CLubID(Number) | Player Name(Text) | PlayerAge(Number)
```

tblClubs fields are:

```
ID(Autonumber) | ClubName (Text)
```

Now I need to show Names of players with maximum ages among other players in their own clubs and the club name beside that like this :

```
Club Name | Player Name | Maximum Age (older player of each club)
```

please tell me how can i make it?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with window functions, if your database supports them:

```
select c.club_name, p.player_name, p.player_age
from clubs c 
inner join (
    select 
        p.*, 
        rank() over(partition by p.club_id order by p.player_age desc) rn 
    players p
) p on p.club_id = c.id and p.rn = 1
```

A common and quite portable alternative is to filter with a subquery:

```
select 
    c.club_name, 
    t.player_name,
    t.player_age
from players p
inner join clubs c on c.id = p.club_id
where p.age = (select max(p1.age) from players p1 where p1.club_id = p.club_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/16430/4)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tblPlayers (ID INT, ClubID INT,PlayerName VARCHAR(255)
                         ,PlayerAge INT)
CREATE TABLE tblClubs (ID int,ClubName VARCHAR(255))   

INSERT INTO tblPlayers(ID,ClubID,PlayerName
                       ,PlayerAge) VALUES (1,1,'John',30)
                       ,(2,1,'Mark',25)
                       ,(3,1,'Albert',36)
                       ,(4,2,'David',33)
                       ,(5,2,'John',31)
INSERT INTO tblClubs(ID, ClubName) VALUES(1,'TEAM 1')
                                  ,(2,'TEAM 2')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT A.*,RANK() OVER 
     (PARTITION BY A.ClubID ORDER BY A.PlayerAge desc) as rn
    FROM tblPlayers A
    INNER JOIN tblClubs B ON A.ClubID=B.ID) t
WHERE
    t.rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/16430/4/0)**:

```
| ID | ClubID | PlayerName | PlayerAge | rn |
|----|--------|------------|-----------|----|
|  3 |      1 |     Albert |        36 |  1 |
|  4 |      2 |      David |        33 |  1 |
```